# php echo page numbers in same line

Tags: php, css, pagination, echo

i have pagination system on my echo results however, the page numbers are being echo'ed underneath eachother

e.g.

```
                              1
                2 3 4 5
```

this is my code:

```
for($i=0;$i < $count1;$i=$i+$limit)
 {
if($i <> $start)
{       
    echo "<a href='view.php?search=$search&start=$i&limit=$limit&price=$price&category=$category'><font face='Verdana' size='2'><b>&nbsp;$l&nbsp;</b></font></a> ";
}
else
{
    echo "<center><font face='Verdana' size='4' color=#2E9AFE ><b>&nbsp;$l&nbsp;</b></font></center>";
}
```

MODIFIED CODE:

```
$i=0;
 $l=1;
   echo "<p align='left'>";
   for($i=0;$i < $count1;$i=$i+$limit)
   {
  if($i <> $start)
   {        
   echo '<a href="view.php?   search=$search&start=$i&limit=$limit&price=$price&category=$category">$i</a>';
}
else
{
   echo '<span class="current">$i</span>';
}        
$l=$l+1;
  }
 echo "</p>";
  }
```

Comment: Just use DIV elements with float: left... Look at my answer.

Comment: what is the `+ $limit` part about? either the variable name is badly named or it's in the wrong location. surely it should be `$i += $step` or `$i++`. Will you ever need your system to jump more than one page at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way of doing the above, with a few added extras:

```
$count1 = 10;    
$menu = '';

$link = array(
  'search' => ( isset($search) ? $search : $search = '' ),
  'start' => ( isset($start) ? $start : $start = 0 ),
  'limit' => ( isset($limit) ? $limit : $limit = 1 ),
  'price' => ( isset($price) ? $price : $price = '' ),
  'category' => ( isset($category) ? $category : $category = '' ),
);

foreach( range(0, $count1, $limit) as $i ) {
  $menu .= ( ($link['start'] = $i) == $start ? 
    '<span class="current">'.$i.'</span>' :
    '<a href="view.php?'.http_build_query($link).'">'.$i.'</a>'
  ) . PHP_EOL;
}

echo $menu;
```

*(the above requires php5+)*

With regards to neeko's comment, to seperate the `$start` variable from the text displayed in the link - all you have to do is either introduce another variable that counts up with each loop - or, as we already have the key of the range array, we can use that:

```
foreach( range(0, $count1, $limit) as $key => $i ) {
  $menu .= ( ($link['start'] = $i) == $start ? 
    '<span class="current">Page'.($key+1).'</span>' :
    '<a href="view.php?'.http_build_query($link).'">Page'.($key+1).'</a>'
  ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I've used `$key + 1`, because `$key` will be zero-based *(i.e. counting up from Zero)* but the +1 just shifts things so we count up from 1 instead.

Comment: thankyou for your reply! this works really well, however, one thing,anyway to get it to show page1, page2 instead of 0, 4, 8

Comment: thanks, is there anyway to get it to show page1, page2... etc ?

Comment: if you look at my answer above you should see a second section of code (you may need to reload the page). This has the modifications that I've just added to show Page1, Page2 and so on... :)

Comment: if there is less than 4 ads i get this error, Warning: range() [function.range]: step exceeds the specified range in public_html/search.php on line 627

Comment: I'm assuming that if there are less than 4 you don't need the pages menu appearing at all? so you could wrap the whole code in an `if ( $count1 >= $limit ) { ... }`. Either that or you could place this before the foreach `if ( $count1 <= $limit ) { $count1 = $limit = 0; }` which will force the range to only return one item - which will render only your "current" page span.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php for($i=0;$i < $count1;$i=$i+$limit): ?>

  <?php if($i <> $start): ?>

 <a href="view.php?search=<?php echo $search;?>&start=<?php echo $i;?>&limit=<?php echo $limit;?>&price=<?php echo $price;?>&category=<?php echo $category;?>">
 <?php echo $i; ?></a>

  <?php else: ?>

  <span class="current"><?php echo $i;?></span>

  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

CSS:

```
a,span.current{font-weight:bold;font-family:Verdana;}
```

All are inline elements, so they'll stay...inline. Add paddings, text-decoration, colors and whatever in your CSS. I could help you to achieve exactly what you want if you are more clear in your intentions (center?). Stay away from old html and tables :)

Comment: +1 whilst I agree with using spans (over divs) you'll need to modify your a link as you currently aren't echo-ing out the $vars.

Comment: @pebbl Thanks, I missed that. Edited accordingly

Comment: @DamienPirsy thankyou for your reply! when i replace this with my code it comes up with an error, do i need to include the <?php ?> tags if its already in a php file?

Comment: Well, no, not the first opening tag in that case. What error do you get? Anyway, that's just short syntax, you can jsut write as you already do, that's not the main point.

Comment: now it echo'es $i instead of the numbers, (but they are in line thanks) any idea how i can fix this? ill add my modified code to the question really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because center is a block element which means it won't be inline with the other numbers (but that isn't my specialty so I might be wrong.  You could put them in a table.

```
echo "<table><tr>";

for($i=0;$i < $count1;$i=$i+$limit)
{
    echo "<td>";
    if($i <> $start)
    {       
        echo "<a href='view.php?search=$search&start=$i&limit=$limit&price=$price&category=$category'><font face='Verdana' size='2'><b>&nbsp;$l&nbsp;</b></font></a> ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<center><font face='Verdana' size='4' color=#2E9AFE ><b>&nbsp;$l&nbsp;</b></font></center>";
    }
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: You are right, center is a block level element, also it's deprecated an shouldn't be used anymore. And i'd say one could call using tables for anything other than tabular data deprecated too ;)

Comment: haha, agreed, I have started using divs but I don't do much html so I'm too rusty with it, so good call.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
for($i=0;$i < $count1;$i=$i+$limit)
{
if($i <> $start)
{       
    echo "<a href='view.php?search=$search&start=$i&limit=$limit&price=$price&category=$category'><div style='font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; float: left; position: relative; padding: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'>$l</div></a>";
}
else
{
    echo "<div style='font-family: verdana; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; float: left; position: relative; color: #2E9AFE; padding: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'>$l</div>";
}
```

I have changed your html part of code to display in div elements with float: left and some other css tweaks so now it should be placed in one line...

Comment: IS the div really necessary? Why using floating blocks when you have already elements lying inline?

Comment: I usually do it with divs, that way I can much easier put some desired styles on it. On the end personally I like divs more :p

Comment: Well, you can give a display:block to an inline element and use it as a div...Your approach isn't semantically correct, and can lead to div soups..Just my 2 cents